# {{store url=" "}} or {{base_secure_url}} or {{base_unsecure_url}} for my situation?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, email, variables

Which one of these is best if I am running one store and the test environment is running unsecure where as production is running secure and we're only planning to have one store in the Magento instance and not multi-store?

If there were more than one store, would this impact the usage of the `{{base_secure_url}}` versus `{{base_unsecure_url}}` or the `{{store url=""}}`?

Thanks!

Comment: use `{{store url=""}}`

Comment: Please add to your answer with justification for this reasoning. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{{store url=“ ”}}`

If your browse store without https it will use url without https.

If your browse store with https it will use url with https.

In your case that is useful for you

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it does this and why it's different?

Comment: `{{base_secure_url}}`  gives value web/secure/base_url of `core_config_data` table   and `{{base_unsecure_url}}`  gives value web/unsecure/base_url of `core_config_data` table. It gives specific url which is stored in database

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate the detail. Is there any reason why they would be different other than http or https or does it get more specific? Is there a reason why it would? Sorry to ask so much! It may help someone else. :)